# jQuery find() method not working on only one(!) class

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's find() method is not working with everything except my class *.szenenkasten*.
It doesn't make any sense at all...

Simplified source code:

HTML

```
<ul class="NavBar">
    <li></li>  
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li> 
    <li></li>         
</ul>

<span class="szenenkasten"></span>
<span class="szenenkasten"></span>
<span class="szenenkasten"></span>
<span class="szenenkasten"></span>
<span class="szenenkasten"></span>
```

jQuery

```
alert($('.NavBar').find('li').length);
 //returns 5
alert($('.szenenkasten').find('span').length);
 //returns 0
alert($('span').find('.szenenkasten').length);
 //returns 0
alert($('span.szenenkasten').length);
//returns 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks among descendants of your jquery elements. Here your span aren't descendant but the same elements.

Don't use find but filter here :

```
alert($('.szenenkasten').filter('span').length);
```

or simply

```
alert($('span.szenenkasten'));
```